# Is there an example dhcpd.conf that contains an example for each option?

Tags: linux, dhcp, isc-dhcpd, dhcpcd

OS: Debian 11

I'm attempting to create an example isc dhcpd.conf which has an entry for each option.  So far I've managed to find about 30 options to include but I can't find the other ~160.  I looked at the dhcp & dhcpd.conf man pages and consulted chatgpt.  Any have such a list they'd be willing to share or point me to where I can look?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol` give you what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From man `dhcpd.conf`:

> REFERENCE: OPTION STATEMENTS
> DHCP option statements are documented in the dhcp-options(5) manual page.

Have a look at `man dhcp-options` or the [online manual](https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-44-manual-pages-dhcp-options).

Comment: Doesn't tell the option number, but good enough.  Seems better than man page in the OS. Thanks.